# Javascript - Why is checkbox always checked?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

If I put this line in my javascript function is leaves the checkbox unchecked as expected.

```
document.getElementById('idTax1').checked=false;
```

Why does it not work when I put it in an if statement and use the return of an array?  I can confirm that data[14] has a value of 0.

```
if (data[14]=1) {document.getElementById('idTax1').checked=true;} 
else {document.getElementById('idTax1').checked=false;}
```

The above always checks the box.  I have also tried the opposite.  I continue to get a checked box.

```
if (data[14]=0) {document.getElementById('idTax1').checked=false;} 
else {document.getElementById('idTax1').checked=true;}
```

Thank you.

Comment: = and == are two very different things :-)

Comment: Why do I have -1 on my question?

Comment: I'm not sure why, it's getting close votes too. It may be a pretty basic question but we all start somewhere. I reversed one of the downvotes.

Comment: Thanks.  I do lots of searching on the net before I post here.  But sometimes I don't even know what to put in the search box to return what I am looking for.  For this one, I had no idea the problem was related to an = sign.  Many tanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (data[14]=1)` would always return true

what you need is `if (data[14]==1)`

= is assignment

== is comparison

also, The identity (===) operator behaves identically to the equality (==) operator except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be considered equal.

Reference: [Javascript Tutorial: Comparison Operators](http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsgrpComparison.htm)

you seem new to javascript. please see this link to learn more about operators

```
= ,==, ===
```

http://www.lanoie.net/classes/DHTML/programming/lectures/lecture6.html

Comment: Awesome.  Can't believe I got stumped by something that easy.

Comment: happens with everyone :P . please accept an answer (for future viewers), if it solves your query.

Comment: So far... on my own with the help of this site and others I manage to do pretty cool stuff with my website.  I am not a programmer yet still was able to build an invoice creation and viewing section on my site.  It included, html, javascript with ajax, css, php and SQL.  All this was new to me.  I had the most difficulty with the ajax statement.  Thanks to everyone.  Do you know why my questions often end up with a -1?

Comment: these kind of errors are quite common and should generally be detected in some time by yourself or by googling. here in stackoverflow, you should not post question without first trying to get a solution by yourself and also not without looking at the possible duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
  if(data[14] == 1) {...}
```

With = you assign a value to a variable.

With == you compare two values.